# Converting from CSS3 to SVG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, css, svg, illustrator-scripting, illustrator-effects

So, I was working on my site and an accidental mistake did a nice 3D effect to my new Logo, is there any way to convert or import a CSS3 code to illustrator so I can have it as .SVG?

Comment: You'll have to recreate it by hand. For most things this really doesn't take as long as you might think

Answer (score 2):

No. Illustrator wouldn't know what to do with CSS and HTML.